# var keyword can change a variable type to dynamic?

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have a service for `Entity1` whose name is `Entity1Service` and it contains a method `GetBySerial` which is responsible for fetch the appropriate document from the database (I used [LiteDb](https://github.com/mbdavid/LiteDB)) and returns it:

```
public class Entity1Service
{
    private readonly LiteCollection<Entity1> _entity1Collection;
    private readonly LiteDatabase _db;

    public Entity1Service()
    {
        _db = new LiteDatabase(Constants.DbFileName);
        _entity1Collection = _db.GetCollection<Entity1>(nameof(Entity1));
    }
    public Entity1 GetBySerial(string serial)
    {
        var q = Query.EQ(nameof(Entity1.Serial), serial);

        lock (Constants.DbLockObj)
        {
            return _entity1Collection.Find(q).SingleOrDefault();
        }
    }
}
```

If I use this method like this:

```
Entity1Service _entity1Service = new Entity1Service();
dynamic MyDynamic = new System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject();
MyDynamic.Serial = "serial";
var e1 = _entity1Service.GetBySerial(MyDynamic.Serial);
```

the `e1` will be a dynamic variable. But, if I use it like this:

```
Entity1 e1 = _entity1Service.GetBySerial("serial");
```

Its type will be `Entity1` as expected. I can't figure out why the compiler acts like this.

I face this behavior in a console application, dotnet core v. 2.1 and C# v. 7.3

**Update:**

Thanks to Jon Skeet, I tried to make a "minimal reproducible example" as he mentioned in a comment. So, during this process, I found that the problem is happened because of a code that I removed from the code for simplicity. So, the problem exactly happens when I pass a dynamic value as the argument to the method. So I edited the first code section.

Comment: What is the type of `entity1Collection`?

Comment: And what's the type of `_entity1Service`? If *that's* `dynamic`, that explains everything - but without that, I would definitely expect the type of `e1` to be `Entity1`. Please provide a [mcve] to show what you're observing, as otherwise it's very hard to help you.

Comment: I've updated my question and clarified the types of objects

Comment: You haven't provided a [mcve] though, so we still can't help you. We still don't even know the compile-time type of `_entity1Service`, and you haven't said how you reached the conclusion that "the `e1` will be a dynamic variable".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't really about `var`. That just showed up something that was already going on in your explicitly-typed code. This is about how dynamic typing works. The result of almost any expression involving `dynamic` is deemed to be `dynamic`.

So in this code:

```cs
Entity1Service _entity1Service = new Entity1Service();
dynamic MyDynamic = new System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject();
MyDynamic.Serial = "serial";
var e1 = _entity1Service.GetBySerial(MyDynamic.Serial);
```

... the compile-time type of `MyDynamic.Serial` is `dynamic`, and the call to `_entity1Service.GetBySerial` is dynamically bound, with a result of `dynamic`. When you explicitly type `e1` as `Entity1`, you're effectively adding a cast after the call.

If you just make sure everything in the expression is statically typed, the result will have the static type you expect. For example, you could cast the argument:

```cs
Entity1Service _entity1Service = new Entity1Service();
dynamic MyDynamic = new System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject();
MyDynamic.Serial = "serial";
var e1 = _entity1Service.GetBySerial((string) MyDynamic.Serial);
```

Or you could use a separate local variable:

```cs
Entity1Service _entity1Service = new Entity1Service();
dynamic MyDynamic = new System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject();
MyDynamic.Serial = "serial";
string serial = MyDynamic.Serial;
var e1 = _entity1Service.GetBySerial(serial);
```

Either way, the `_entity1Service.GetBySerial` call is now statically bound - which is almost certainly what you want - and the type of `e1` will be `Entity1`.